# PHP and HTML Forms for particular task

Tags: php, html, forms

Guys here is my html form code. What I want is when I click submit button. The php code should check which check boxes are checked and than for each check boxed it should do particular task. like if 
check Hospitals, Businesses, and Real Estate check boxes then it should do particular task like echo'hospitals', echo'businesses' and echo''real estate' Thanks in advance.

```
    <form action="Restaurant.php"  method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
       <label for="file">Filename:</label>
 <input type="file" name="file" id="file" />
           <input type="checkbox" name="Templates" value="Restaurant"/>

  <input type="checkbox" name="Templates1" value="Hospitals" />Hospitals

 <input type="checkbox" name="Templates2" value="Businesses" />Businesses

 <input type="checkbox" name="Templates3" value="RealEstate" />Real Estate

       <input type="checkbox" name="Templates4" value="CarDealership" />Car Dealership

    <input type="checkbox" name="Templates5" value="Sports" />Sports

 <input type="checkbox" name="Templates6" value="Hotels" />Hotels

 <input type="checkbox" name="Templates7"value="Home" />Home

  <input type="checkbox" name="Templates8" value="Advertisement" />Advertisement



   <br />
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" />
          </form>
```

Comment: So this is just like the previous question you asked, except this time, you've not included your PHP code?

Comment: I only see this question listed on the OP's profile.

Comment: Please ask an actual question to a problem you're having, not a design document statement of how you want something made.

Comment: why you guys messing around if you don't want to answer question don't do it. but don't mark me down

Comment: @user1689855 the downvote system was put in place for a reason. Nobody is "messing around" -- it's simply a way to discourage users from posting questions, well...like this one

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edit:

```
for($i=0; $i<=count($_POST);$i++) {
  if ($_POST["Templates$i") === 'Hospitals' && $_POST["Templates$i") === 'Businesses') { //do something...} 
    else if ($_POST["Templates$i") === 'Businesses') { //do something...} 

}
```

Comment: this is just going to be either one of them, but if it choose both the check boxes. hospitals and businesses.

Comment: thn you just add AND `&&` in the if statement. `if ($_POST["Templates$i") === 'Hospitals' && $_POST["Templates$i") === 'Businesses') {  //do something...} `

Comment: thank you i actually understand it letter. when i went through whole coed

Comment: hi sorry to disturb you but the code is not working after first loop

Comment: ok, i edited the answer, have a look.

Comment: see this is easy when you have 2 to 3 choices but think about when you have 7 or 8.

Comment: what do u mean by 7 or 8 choices? do you want to compare 7 or 8 of them? then just make `if` statements accordingly.

Comment: choices of check boxes listed in code above

Comment: i want to run specific php script when that particular checkbox is checked

Comment: :) you need to start researching (Google) the basics of writing php code. start with reading about `if-statement` with examples, you will get the idea.